# Issue with Scala Implicit Conversions

Tags: scala, generics, implicit-conversion, implicit

In the below code excerpt, the last statement does not compile. However, the statement immediately before that one does in fact compile. This second-to-last statement is what I would expect the compiler would convert the last statement to. I do not understand why it does not work. Any help is appreciated.

```
trait ParameterizedBy[A, B] {
    val parameterized: B
  }

object ParameterizedBy {
  implicit def toParameterized[A, B, C](p: ParameterizedBy[A, B])(
    implicit f: B => C): C = f(p.parameterized)
}

trait Wraps[A] {
  val wrapped: A
}

object Wraps {
  implicit def toWrapped[A](w: Wraps[A]): A = w.wrapped
}

val p = new ParameterizedBy[String, Wraps[Int]] {
  override val parameterized: Wraps[Int] = new Wraps[Int] {
    override val wrapped = 6
  }
}

ParameterizedBy.toParameterized(p)(Wraps.toWrapped) + 5

p + 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicitly converting a method into `A => C` is problematic, because the compiler cannot easily enumerate *all* the possible classes `C` that have the expected method `+`, and then go and search *all* the possible methods which take `B` and give `C` - this search would take forever.

I'd suggest to avoid implicit arguments of type `B => C` for unknown type `C`. If you want a converter, then give it some specific name, e.g.

```
trait Unwrap[A, B] extends (A => B)
```

that you then use only in this chained implicit.

A rough sketch of what you might try instead:

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

trait ParameterizedBy[A, B] {
    val parameterized: B
  }

object ParameterizedBy {
  implicit def toParameterized[A, B, C](p: ParameterizedBy[A, B])(
    implicit f: Unwrap[B, C]): C = f(p.parameterized)
}

trait Wraps[A] {
  val wrapped: A
}

object Wraps {
  implicit def toWrapped[A](w: Wraps[A]): A = w.wrapped
}

trait Unwrap[A, B] extends (A => B)

object Unwrap {
  implicit def unwrap[A]: Unwrap[Wraps[A], A] = new Unwrap[Wraps[A], A] {
    def apply(w: Wraps[A]): A = w.wrapped
  }
}

val p = new ParameterizedBy[String, Wraps[Int]] {
  override val parameterized: Wraps[Int] = new Wraps[Int] {
    override val wrapped = 6
  }
}

p - 5         // works
(p: Int) + 5  // works with type ascription (to avoid conflicts with `+ String`)
```